# Open Sound Control (OSC) in c#

Tags: c#, libraries, osc

I bought TouchOSC app for my iPod Touch, because I thought it would be easy to find a library to use osc protocol in c#. I would like to develop an application using c#, but haven't found one yet. Would someone know about any good libraries to do osc in c#? I found some topic where it mentioned c++ libraries.. In case there are not exist c# libraries, I can use c++ libraries?

Comment: This question could probably be cleaned up a bit, but I actually feel its a valid question.

Comment: Cleaned up the question a bit hopefully it's a little better, but it might not be enough?

Comment: if you had to use C++ library, you maybe able to wrap it in C#. I am actually looking for a good C# library myself, I will let you know if I come up with something good. Cheers!

Comment: @nagates: library recommendation questions are offtopic

Comment: @PlasmaHH, fair enough. I guess my question would be then, how does one get help in finding a good library, as some may be obscure, or not even worth people's time. I feel it's a valid question to ask those in the know, which libraries are bad or difficult to use.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, I guess I could see where this gets tricky because it could become VERY opinionated really fast. I guess I would like to know, should the OP, research libraries before hand, and ask for suggestions on each, idk.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i dont know if you will find what you need in this library.
http://opensoundcontrol.org/implementation/osc-net-v1-2

Comment: did you used this library before?

Comment: The link says "Not Found - The requested URL /implementation/osc-net-v1-2 was not found on this server."

Answer (score 0):

There was an osc open source implementation from luvtechno.net (this website seems to be down now tho).

You can find source code [here](https://github.com/vvvv/vvvv-sdk/tree/develop/common/src/core/Utils/OSC)

Used it extensively and it works really well (if you need a sample let me know, but it should be pretty simple to use).

Comment: Hey could you post a sample?